# Создание базы данных в libgdx

Tags: java, android, база-данных, sqlite, libgdx

Как создать в libgdx базу данных sqlite? Я нашёл на этом же сайте совет https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874824/using-a-sqlite-database-in-libgdx, но так и не понял, как её установить (я пока новенький). Если можете, пожалуйста, распишите шаги подробно)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В libgdx нет sqlite. По ссылке делают так. Создают в модуле core абстрактный класс DataBase. Потом расшряют этот абстрактный класс на DatabaseDesktop для модуля desktop и DatabaseAndroid для модуля android. В приципе можно скопировать код по ссылке и поираться с ним.

Comment: Прошу прощения, но во втором ответе есть ссылка на github https://github.com/mrafayaleem/gdx-sqlite , где говориться о возможности установки этой библиотеки. К сожалению, я не понимаю, как её установить. Если Вы можете помочь, пожалуйста помогите

Comment: Там последний коммит был аж в 2014 году. Я бы не стал ее использовать. Но по сути в gdx-sqlite сделано также как написано по ссылке в вопросе. Если хочешь использовать библиотеку gdx-sqlite, то сначала скачай этот архив http://bit.ly/gdx-sqlite, там будут jar-файлы. Их надо прописать в gradle. Если хочешь самостоятельно работать с sqlite, то можешь тут посмотреть https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite, но это только для андроида. Для десктопа надо отдельно реализовать поддержку sqlite.

Comment: А как именно и что прописывать? Я пишу приложение для только android

Comment: В модуле core надо создать папку libs и скопировать туда gdx-sqlite.jar. В модуль android в папку libs скопировать gdx-sqlite-android.jar. В модуль desktop в папку libs - gdx-sqlite-desktop.jar. Затем в корне проекта в build.gradle в project(":core") в dependencies прописать api files('libs/gdx-sqlite.jar'). В остальных модулях сделать по аналогии.